# Combining multiple function arguments inside list2serv(lapply(),)

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm working with ten training datasets, train1 through train10, and would like to repeat the following statements for 1 through 10 with a single block of code:

```
  train_y_1 <- c(train1$y)
  train1$y <-NULL
  train_x_1 <- data.matrix(train1) 
  olsfit_1 <- cv.glmnet(y=train_y_1, x=train_x_1, alpha=1, family="gaussian")
```

I've read in the forums that lapply() is preferable to for loops. My code:

```
# Create empty data frames and list (to be populated with values in main program) 
list2env(setNames(lapply(1:10, function(i) data.frame()), paste0('train_y_', 1:10)), envir=.GlobalEnv)
list2env(setNames(lapply(1:10, function(i) data.frame()), paste0('train_x_', 1:10)), envir=.GlobalEnv)
list2env(setNames(lapply(1:10, function(i) list()), paste0('lasso_', 1:10)), envir=.GlobalEnv)

# Create y and x input matrices and run ten lasso regressions
  list2env(lapply(mget(paste0('train', 1:10)), mget(paste0('train_y_', 1:10)), mget(paste0('train_x_', 1:10)), mget(paste0('lasso_', 1:10)), 
  function(a,b,c,d) 
  {
    b <- c(a$y);
    a$y <- NULL;
    c <- data.matrix(a); 
    d <- cv.glmnet(y=b, x=c, alpha=1, family="gaussian");
  }), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

which produces the error message:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'mget(paste0("train_y_", 1:10))' is not a function, character or symbol
```

So it looks like R is confused by the four mget() functions which I intended to be reading in values for the a,b,c,d arguments, but I'm not sure how to proceed next.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep all your data in lists whenever possible, avoiding polluting the global environment with a bunch of variables.  This isn't tested, and `train` is missing, but should be a similar list of your train data.  Then, you could do something like,

```
trainy <- setNames(lapply(1:10, function(i) data.frame()), paste0('train_y_', 1:10))
trainx <- setNames(lapply(1:10, function(i) data.frame()), paste0('train_x_', 1:10))
lasso <- setNames(lapply(1:10, function(i) list()), paste0('lasso_', 1:10))

f <-   function(a,b,c,d) {
    b <- c(a$y);
    a$y <- NULL;
    c <- data.matrix(a); 
    d <- cv.glmnet(y=b, x=c, alpha=1, family="gaussian");
}

mapply(f, train, trainy, trainx, lasso, SIMPLIFY=F)
```

Although, since your lists are just initializing variables, you probably just want to loop (`apply`) over a list of your training data,

```
lapply(train, function(x) {
    ...        # the statements you want to repeat
    list(...)  # return a list of the three data.frames
})
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I added "train <- lapply(1:10, function(x) {paste0("train", x)})" for the train1-train10 list. I'm getting an error message: "Error in a$y : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" when I run the code

Comment: @RobertF `train` should be a list of your actual training datasets, if I am reading this right.  So, if you have all of them in your global environment, I think something like `train <- mget(paste0("train", 1:10))`

Comment: Much better, thank you! The program seems to run OK although it's not saving the output data frames for b, c, and d.

Comment: @RobertF in your function, `f`, if you want to return multiple values, wrap them in a list, ie `list(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)`

Comment: Got it, much appreciated.

Comment: @RobertF no problem, HTH

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this with the following code.

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr);library(glmnet)
# Gather all the variables in global into a list
fit = mget(paste0("train", 1:10), envir = .GlobalEnv) %>%
# Pipe each element of the list into `cv.glmnet` function     
      lapply(function(dat) {cv.glmnet(y = dat$y,
                            x = data.matrix(dat %>% mutate(y = NULL)),
                            alpha = 1,
                            family = "gaussian")})
```

Your output will be neatly stored in `fit`, which is a list with 10 elements. You can call each element with `fit[[i]]`. For example `coef(fit[[1]])` pulls out the coefs for `train1` and `lapply(fit, coef)` pulls the coef for all 10 models and stores them in a list.

Comment: Thanks Vlo, this is fantastic! I'll have to educate myself about the %>% operator. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error message: 'Error: could not find function "%>%" ' after running your code.

Comment: @RobertF Did you run `library(dplyr)` sucessfully?

Comment: Yep that was it - the code worked perfectly. Thanks again